# Один Мakefile для компиляции c помощью C и С++ компиляторов

Tags: c++, c, makefile

Есть следующий Makefile:

```
.PHONY: clean

LEX = lex
YACC = yacc
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -m32
CXXFLAGS = -m32

bcpp: lex.yy.o y.tab.o execute.o global.o load.o main.o storage.o util.o libtask.a
    $(CC) lex.yy.o y.tab.o main.o storage.o util.o -L. -lbc -ltask -o bcpp $(CXXFLAGS)
bc: lex.yy.o y.tab.o execute.o global.o load.o main.o storage.o util.o libtask.a
    $(CC) lex.yy.o y.tab.o main.o storage.o util.o -L. -lbc -ltask -o bc $(CFLAGS)
lex.yy.c: scan.l
    $(LEX) scan.l
y.tab.c y.tab.h: bc.y
    $(YACC) -d bc.y
lex.yy.o: lex.yy.c y.tab.h
    $(CC) -c lex.yy.c $(CFLAGS)
y.tab.o: y.tab.c y.tab.h
    $(CC) -c y.tab.c $(CFLAGS)
execute.o: execute.c bcdefs.h global.h proto.h
    $(CC) -c execute.c $(CFLAGS)
global.o: global.c bcdefs.h global.h libmath.h
    $(CC) -c global.c $(CFLAGS)
load.o: load.c bcdefs.h global.h proto.h
    $(CC) -c load.c $(CFLAGS)
libtask.a: execute.o global.o load.o
    ar -cvq libtask.a execute.o global.o load.o
main.o: main.c bcdefs.h global.h proto.h getopt.h
    $(CC) -c main.c $(CFLAGS)
storage.o: storage.c bcdefs.h global.h proto.h
    $(CC) -c storage.c $(CFLAGS)
util.o: util.c bcdefs.h global.h proto.h
    $(CC) -c util.c $(CFLAGS)
clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *.yy.*
    rm -f *.tab.*
    rm -f libtask.a
    rm -f bc
    rm -f bcpp
```

Для компиляции с помощью компилятора С использую следующую команду:

**make bc**

Всё компилируется без проблем.

А для компиляции с помощью компилятора С++ использую следующую команду:

**make CC=g++ bcpp**

И получаю такой набор ошибок:

```
lex scan.l
yacc -d bc.y
bc.y: warning: 3 shift/reduce conflicts [-Wconflicts-sr]
g++ -c lex.yy.c -m32
In file included from scan.l:33:0:
global.h:151:12: error: previous declaration of ‘int optind’ with ‘C++’ linkage
 extern int optind;
            ^
In file included from /usr/include/unistd.h:871:0,
                 from lex.yy.c:912:
/usr/include/getopt.h:71:12: error: conflicts with new declaration with ‘C’ linkage
 extern int optind;
            ^
In file included from bcdefs.h:58:0,
                 from scan.l:32:
scan.l:51:16: error: previous declaration of ‘int yywrap()’ with ‘C++’ linkage
 _PROTOTYPE(int yywrap, (void));
                ^
number.h:96:32: note: in definition of macro ‘_PROTOTYPE’
 #define _PROTOTYPE(func, args) func args
                                ^
lex.yy.c:956:29: error: conflicts with new declaration with ‘C’ linkage
 extern "C" int yywrap (void );
                             ^
scan.l: In function ‘int yylex()’:
scan.l:227:38: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
       yyerror ("illegal character: #");
                                      ^
scan.l:298:24: error: ‘input’ was not declared in this scope
      while ( ((c=input()) != '*') && (c != EOF)) 
                        ^
scan.l:303:20: error: ‘input’ was not declared in this scope
   while ( (c=input()) == '*') /* eat it*/;
                    ^
scan.l:324:59: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
        if (count != 2) yyerror ("NUL character in string.");
                                                           ^
scan.l:356:55: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
      yyerror ("illegal character: ^%c",yytext[0] + '@');
                                                       ^
scan.l:359:61: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
        yyerror ("illegal character: \\%03o", (int) yytext[0]);
                                                             ^
scan.l:361:47: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
        yyerror ("illegal character: %s",yytext);
                                               ^
make: *** [lex.yy.o] Error 1
```

Можно ли решить как-то данную проблему?

Comment: Чем оправдана потребность в компиляции то C, то C++ компилятором?

Answer (score 3):

Ошибки всязаны с попыткой скомпилировать c-код c++ компилятором. В общем случае это невозможно (языки разные).
Иногда можно поправить код так чтобы он компилировался обоими компиляторами. Например в number.h (строка 96) написать:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define extern "C" _PROTOTYPE(func, args) func args
#iflse //__cplusplus
#define  _PROTOTYPE(func, args) func args
#endif
```

И далее подобные правки по остальным ошибкам компиляии...
Простого решения не будет. Лучьше понять что привело к необходимости компилировать С программу С++ компилятором, и решить эту проблему.